# How to handle default values for a DateTime type in Doctrine2 SELECT query?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following Doctrine2 entity:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Account
{
    use TimestampableEntity;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    private $id;
}
```

As you can see I am using [Gedmo Timestampable](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md) with the [Trait](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md#traits) provided by the bundle. It's working fine.

The problem happen when I fetch the data and the column `updated_at` is coming as <strike>`NULL`</strike> `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. For such case the `DateTime` object is translated into an *invalid* date as shown below:

```
‌array (
  'RowId' => 26944,
  'synchflag' => 1,
  'updatedAt' => 
  DateTime::__set_state(array(
     'date' => '-0001-11-30 00:00:00.000000',
     'timezone_type' => 3,
     'timezone' => 'UTC',
  )),
)
```

I did check [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html) but there isn't anything helpful (or at least I didn't found it if you do let me know)

What is the right way to deal with this?

**EDIT:**

Maybe the right question here should be: if `updated_at` is coming as `0000-00-00 00:00:00` how do I turn it into `NOW()`? As you may notice the `getUpdatedAt()` return a `DateTime` based on the fetched data. Is there any event for `SELECT` statement?

Comment: In my entities updated_at are set equal to created_at. Did not face with this trouble

Comment: Can you debug why your updatedAt attribute is null? Creating entity triggers setting createdAt/updatedAt attributes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the problem is that the database already have those invalid values, you can create your own doctrine datetime type to make the conversion to null when reading that invalid value from the database:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Doctrine\DBAL;

use DateTimeZone;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ConversionException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType;

class MyDateTimeType extends DateTimeType
{


   public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
   {
       if (null === $value || $value instanceof \DateTime) {
           return $value;
       }

       if ('0000-00-00 00:00:00' === $value) {
          return null;
       }

       return parent::convertToPHPValue($value, $platform);
   }
}
```

And register this custom type in doctrine configuration:

```
doctrine:
   dbal:
       types:
           datetime: AppBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\MyDateTimeType
```

Note: you can enhanced this code using regexp and/or datetime validity checking instead of a simple comparison