# Doctrine ORM: NULL to DateTime conversion error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I use PHP7, Symfony 2.8 andDoctrine ORM 2.5.
I have an entity with a datetime field:

```
 /** @ORM\Column(name="data_ordine", type="datetime", nullable=true) */
private $dataOrdine;

/**
 * @param mixed $dataOrdine
 */
public function setDataOrdine($dataOrdine = null)
{
    $this->dataOrdine = $dataOrdine;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getDataOrdine()
{
    return $this->dataOrdine;
}
```

When i try to get the $dataOrdine field ($ordine->getDataOrdine()) of a persisted entity on MySQL database if the dataOrdine column is NULL i got:

```
object(DateTime)#551 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(27) "-0001-11-30 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

instead of NULL

Comment: Are you sure than the entity date is null in the database? I'm almost certain than the date of your entity is not null but empty.You should also edit the signature to `setDataOrdine(\DateTime $dataOrdine = null)`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue some time ago. As *@goto* said your column is not coming as `NULL` because `new DateTime(NULL)` is a valid statement.

As this is exactly what happened to me I am entirely sure that the value for the problematic row is coming as `0000-00-00 00:00:00` which makes `new DateTime('0000-00-00 00:00:00')` to return the wrong date.

```php
$null_date = new DateTime(null);
$wrong_date = new DateTime('0000-00-00 00:00:00');

var_dump($null_date);
var_dump($wrong_date);

object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-01-17 13:22:01.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(10) "US/Pacific"
}

object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(27) "-0001-11-30 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(10) "US/Pacific"
}
```

I've got a workaround which I didn't like at all and instead of what is posted and accepted as an answer I made the DBA to no allow NULL|invalid dates at those columns.

More info at: [How to handle default values for a DateTime type in Doctrine2 SELECT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398663/how-to-handle-default-values-for-a-datetime-type-in-doctrine2-select-query)

Answer (score 1):

Some clients show null for 0000-00-00 00:00:00 values. So check via the command line client to be sure (CLI shows correct values). And then just update to null where the value is 0000-00-00 00:00:00